# Update qty on cart page doesn't work because of formkey conflict

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, varnish, form-key

**Configuration**: Varnish + Pagecache module, Redirect all pages to www. in htaccess

**Issue**: Whenever someone hits non-www page a PAGECACHE_FORMKEY cookie is stored. Then they get redirected to www. and another PAGECACHE_FORMKEY cookie is stored but with a different value.

[image]

My code has the formkey:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Tried with:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"/>
```

Still doesn't work, as `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()` outputs the second formkey. If I delete the first PAGECACHE_FORMKEY then it will work.

How can I bypass formkey verification on `checkout/cart/updatePost`?

(This has nothing to do with my theme, it happens with the default theme too, so I guess it is an issue with the connection that PageCache module establishes between varnish and the magento application. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to disable formkey validation on the `checkout_cart_updatePost` event.

```
function disableCsrf($observer)
{
    $events = array(   
        'checkout_cart_updatePost',
    );
    $route = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();

    if (in_array($route, $events)) {
        $key = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('form_key', $key);
    }
}
```

Same as in `SupportDesk_CartFormKey` module.